# Need help making my formula search for exact strings

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to use the FIND function to find multiple strings in the context of a larger formula. The original formula I'm basing it off of is as follows:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("INC",A1))," ","Y")
```

Obviously, this yields a "Y" if it finds whatever text in " ". However, I have many strings that I'd like to check and they need to be exact; i.e. when I search "INC" and "inc", I do not want "Inc" to be counted. So, I tried the following formulas.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(OR("INC",inc"),A1))," ","Y")
=IF(SUM(COUNTIF(A1,"* INC*","* inc*}))," ","Y")
```

The second one works best, but it also counts "Inc in" as a match. Any suggestions?

Comment: For exact match you should use the first one. A second one (with wildcard inc*) will return any string like: "inc in", etc. Rgds,

Comment: When you say "Many strings" do you mean around 10 or around 100?

Comment: [`FIND`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/find-findb-functions-HP010342526.aspx) is case-sensitive. [`SEARCH`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/search-searchb-functions-HP010062577.aspx) is case-insensitive. You're using `FIND`, so "Inc" will not be found when you are looking for "INC". What is the problem then?

Comment: @Michael Petrotta the title now seems misleading. I do not want comments on EXACT functions nor Filters or Ctrl+F finds. Also, to have stricken my disclaim when you or another admin placed an ill-conceived allegation of duplicate questions shows lack of diligence in reading my question and consideration to the effect it would have on people answering my question.

Comment: @bendataclear are you being facetious? because, as of right now, 86 and I am continuously adding more.

Comment: @GSerg the problem is the first formula will not run. It returns the "too many arguments" error box if you put more than one " " in the find function. And I am having trouble with the syntax of the 2nd find formula (one containing OR)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you want.  However, the following formula will return TRUE if any of the substrings are found in A1:

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(FIND({"inc","INC"},A1)))
```

Note that the different strings to search for are within an array constant.  The find will return an array of either #VALUE! if not found, or a number if found.

Comment: @ Ron Rosenfeld That looks like what I need. I'm trying to have a formula search phrases like "Aarhus University Research Foundation Inc" and be able to distinguish between Inc, INC, and inc, and about 83 other strings. If I added a IF statement to that would I be able to have it return a "Yes" or "No"?

Comment: @user3812367 Yes.  The formula I provided would be the **logical_test** portion of the IF function.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what your goal is without sample data and expected results, but I would guess that something like this should work for you:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(FIND({"INC","inc"},A1)))>0,"Found one or more values","No matches")
```